# Javascript hangs in IE unless in debug mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js, less

I'm building web a javascript application using jquery, knockoutjs and less (for css).

Works fine in all browsers, except IE 9 (only tried IE 9).

It simply never starts. Nothing from the templates are shown. Unless i press F12 for debug and refresh. Then everything works fine, also works if I close the debug window and refresh. Right until next IE restart.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using console.log anywhere?  That will break in IE unless the debug tools are open.

Comment: Ah, of course. Thought I had that fixed with my little `if  (!console)
    {
        console = {};
    }
    if (!console.log)
    {
        console.log = function(data){};
    }`

Comment: Yes, it works now. After I just put 'var' in front of the console declaration.. Thanks a lot! (can't accept answer before 15 mins..)

Comment: This has been bugging me for half an hour now.  Stinkin' IE.